# "The service is temporarily unavailable" vs. "...not available"

Tags: differences, negation, prefixes, un-not

Is there a difference? Both versions are common.

If there is a difference, which do I use when, and why?

Comment: I should have asked something with: negation vs. not

Comment: I think you need to clarify your question; I assumed you were  asking the difference between '_temporarily unavailable_' and '_not available_', rather than the difference between '_temporarily unavailable_' and '_temporarily not available_' which seems to be the case.

Comment: If I see "temporarily unavailable" I may come back. With just "unavailable" or "not available" I probably won't.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Grammatically they are interchangeable.  The very definition of "unavailable" is "not available".  However, my gut tells me something else.  When I see 'unavailable' it immediately connotes that it's a temporary condition:

> The senator was unavailable for comment.  *He may be available later.*
>
> The web page was unavailable all afternoon.   *But then it came back online.*

Whereas when I see 'not available' it implies to me that it's a stronger or more permanent situation.  Maybe because of the emphasized *not*?

> This service is not available in New York.  *And it's not likely to be any time soon.*
>
> The web page is not available outside the company.  *Because it's private.*

While you could legitimately substitute "not available" for "unavailable" in those examples (and vice-versa), I wouldn't.

Comment: If google has any credibility, it backs you up there. *"Not available at any price"* gets 4000K hits against only 152K for the *un-* version, and I'd say *"at any price"* usually implies permanence. For a more temporary context, *"Not available today"* gets only 108K hits, but the *un-* version there gets 166K. That looks like a huge switch based purely on the likelihood of future availability.

Answer (score 6):

Both are perfectly valid, but I would take issue with the implications of OP's *"Both versions are common"* - relatively speaking, [they're not](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=temporarily%20unavailable,temporarily%20not%20available&year_start=1950&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3)...

[image]

In short, *unavailable* is the standard form. But noting OP's comment regarding *negation vs. not*, I suggest that, for example...

> *This service is not available to our viewers in Northern Ireland*.

...is normally preferred over...

> **This service is unavailable to our viewers in Northern Ireland*.

Both OP's versions mean exactly the same, but as @Lynn says, the reason *"un-"* is more common is *because it's temporary*. With something more "permanent", like my example above, or the more extreme *"Not available at any price"*, the *"un-"* version is actually [significantly less common](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=unavailable%20at%20any%20price,not%20available%20at%20any%20price&year_start=1940&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3).

Answer (score 3):

They both mean the same, they are just different constructions.

*Temporarily unavailable* seems "lighter", as it contains only 2 words, whereas *temporarily not available* contains 3, which are redundant, as *unavailable* is a grammatical word which bears all the required meaning.

Use less words, be easier and faster to understand.

Answer (score -3):

*Unavailable* is something never will be available.
And *not available* is something is not available right now, but next with some health will be available.

Comment: A quick search provides a lot of uses of "temporarily unavailable". So, either the whole world is wrong, or you are.