# "Unavailable" vs. "not available"

Tags: meaning, differences, adjectives, negation

What is the difference between *unavailable* and *not available*?

In my opinion, *unavailable* is something that will never be available, while *not available* is something that is not available right now but might become available in the future.

Comment: This [question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/50276/the-service-is-temporarily-unavailable-vs-not-available) might help you on this.

Comment: As an aside, you do not say "difference between vs". Vs already *means* "between". So either simply "X vs. Y", or "difference between X and Y", but not a mix of both. As a further aside, one punctuation mark is enough. Do not duplicate things. As one last aside, why on Earth is this tagged "when" and "which-that"?

Comment: @RegDwigнt♦ you are right !! I Don't see that .. The both is same !! And i know this fact

Comment: And you don't say "the both is," either.

Answer (score -3):

Actually there is no difference between these two expressions. Both are interchangeable.

Comment: What are your grounds for this answer?